# Does Samsung S4 support BLE application?

Tags: android, apk, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

Recently I received a Samsung S4 with android 4.2.2 and now I am trying to install BLE apk for testing some things.
I would like to know is there any BLE apk available for android 4.2.2?
I downloaded an apk from the following site but does not work, maybe it just supports by android 4.3. 
http://redbearlab.com/bleshield#AndroidQuickStart

Comment: Yup, Android 4.3 (API Level 18) introduces built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, [Google's BLE SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) is only available starting with Android 4.3. However, you can utilize [Samsung's BLE SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/ble) starting with 4.2.